# Getting a strange error 403 forbidden for accessing an API through python

Tags: python, sendgrid, http-status-code-403, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to access some email stats: My code:

```
import json
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.stats import *
from sendgrid import *

# NOTE: you will need move this file to the root directory of this project to execute properly.

# Assumes you set your environment variable:
# https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#environment-variables-and-your-sendgrid-api-key
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SG****'))


def pprint_json(json_raw):
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_raw), indent=2, sort_keys=True))



def build_global_stats():
    global_stats = Stats()
    global_stats.start_date = '2020-01-13'
    global_stats.end_date = '2020-01-14'
    global_stats.aggregated_by = 'day'
    return global_stats.get()



def get_global_stats():
    stats_params = build_global_stats()
    response = sg.client.stats.get(query_params=stats_params)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.headers)
    pprint_json(response.body)


get_global_stats()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-cee8ef5434a2>", line 35, in <module>
    get_global_stats()

  File "<ipython-input-10-cee8ef5434a2>", line 29, in get_global_stats
    response = sg.client.stats.get(query_params=stats_params)

  File "C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 262, in http_request
    self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)

  File "C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 178, in _make_request
    raise exc

ForbiddenError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN
```

As can be noticed, I get this forbidden error. What is the reason for this?How do i solve this? this is not a blocked site on my end, so not sure why I get this error

Comment: Error 403 means no permision. Did you tried the same requests with Curl?

Comment: Does the client require an authentication or login?

Answer (score 9):

For me, it only works after add a new sender on SendGrid and uses this sender on the "**from**" parameter.

Follow this tutorial:

> https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/senders/

then, go to the email registered and confirm the Sender Identity. After that, you should be able to send emails.

Comment: Thanks I had a typo on my from_email.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit the privileges for your API key in the SendGrid console [here](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys). Click the gear icon to the right of the API key you want to edit, select "Edit API Key" and you can fine-tune the permissions for that key.

Comment: Which permission is missing though?

Comment: @guival It depends on what you're trying to do. What call is failing for you?

Comment: the api v3 send call, I almost definitely know it's because I'm using an unverified from email (sending works perfectly when I use my verified domain or verified single senders), but getting a 403 with no further message doesn't really help. Also I see a lot of examples of people doing this and just having a "sent via sendgrid" added to their from.

Answer (score 2):

Change the permission of the api key to full and and add a new sender email in sendgrip web and verify the sender email. then try the sendmail().

this flow worked for me

Comment: Why is changing the api key permission necessary?

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to update the From field in the message body to the verified ail account associated with the sendGrid account.

Using Single Sender Authentication
verify a single email e.g. hutch@gmail.com
Which will then allow you to send out emails from: hutch@gmail.com via your SendGrid API KEY

Answer (score 1):

I got this rectified by Verifying the sender. Once triggered the verification from Settings > Verify a Single Sender.
The From mailId will get a verification email from SendGrid, simple verification is sufficient to get it reflected as directed in email.

Once verified, you will see an Verified icon, else otherwise.

[image]

Comment: works, tnx my dude!